# Intranet Site appears as white screen that says run();

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use mediawiki to run a small internal wiki page on an Ubuntu server. I upgraded the Ubuntu to 16.04.2 and now when I try to load my wiki page, it just says run();
I am assuming this is something to do with the apache2, but I will be honest in saying that I am not super familiar with Linux command line. Most of what I have done has been over many hours and lots of google.

Any help in this would be great, I'm hoping it is just something stupid. I checked the LocalSettings.php for my mediawiki and nothing seems to have changed on that end of the deal.

Answer (score 0):

The output you describe is the code of MediaWiki's index.php page. This is probably cause because there is a problem with your PHP config, so the page doesn't get parsed, but just directly sent to the browser.

Check if the PHP module is loaded in Apache:

`$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load`

If the `ls` command has no output, enable the PHP module with:

```
sudo a2enmod php5 && sudo service apache2 restart
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, check `/var/log/apache2/errors.log` and post the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. Thank you very much. Your answer led me to find that apache was not starting properly with an error in the .conf file. So I installed php 7.0 and enabled that instead, then apache was able to load and my mediawiki site along with it.

Comment: If the other answer solved the problem for you, you can accept it by clicking the tick beside it. If it did not, it would be helpful to give more details for someone else in a similar situation to follow.